# How to exclude string from tuple to show the integer values only?

Tags: python, tuples, mean

I am trying to find the mean from this dataset and instead I got the error :

> unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'

And the code goes like :

```
dataset = [
            {"name": "John",  "distance": 5602,  "max-speed": 504, "min-speed":798},
            {"name": "Mike",  "distance": 5242,  "max-speed": 622, "min-speed":87},
            {"name": "Chad",  "distance": 4825,  "max-speed": 453, "min-speed":34},
            {"name": "Phil",  "distance": 611,   "max-speed": 500, "min-speed":93},
            {"name": "Tyler", "distance": 5436,  "max-speed": 909, "min-speed":123}
] 

{x_avr : sum(data[x_avr] for data in dataset)/len(dataset) for x_avr in dataset[0]}
```

I know it would get the error since there is data-string inside the dataset.

But I want to know if there was a solution to exclude the string-type data and only show the int type output.

The output that I want :

```
{'distance': 4343.2, 'max-speed': 597.6, 'min-speed': 83.6}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: That's because it's trying to add the values of key "names"

Comment: @bigbounty yup, that's why I want to know how to exclude the key "names" with one liner code :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `isinstance()`.

**Ex:**

```
print( {x_avr : sum(data[x_avr] for data in dataset if isinstance(data[x_avr], int))/len(dataset) for x_avr in dataset[0]} )
```

Answer (score 1):

This is easy with Pandas:

```
import pandas as pd

pd.DataFrame(dataset).mean()
distance     4343.2
max-speed     597.6
min-speed     227.0
```

It's doable, but less pretty, in base Python:

```
[sum([d[key] for d in dataset])/len([d[key] for d in dataset]) for key in dataset[0].keys() if isinstance(dataset[0][key], int)]
[4343.2, 597.6, 227.0]
```

Comment: Yup, Pandas would be easy. I see the isinstance() is the solution. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
(sum([data['distance'] for data in dataset]))/len(dataset)
(sum([data['max-speed'] for data in dataset]))/len(dataset)
(sum([data['min-speed'] for data in dataset]))/len(dataset)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
distance = []
maxspeed = []
minspeed = []

dataset = [
            {"name": "John",  "distance": 5602,  "max-speed": 504, "min-speed":798},
            {"name": "Mike",  "distance": 5242,  "max-speed": 622, "min-speed":87},
            {"name": "Chad",  "distance": 4825,  "max-speed": 453, "min-speed":34},
            {"name": "Phil",  "distance": 611,   "max-speed": 500, "min-speed":93},
            {"name": "Tyler", "distance": 5436,  "max-speed": 909, "min-speed":123}
]


for item in dataset:
    if item['distance']:
        distance.append(item['distance'])

    if item['max-speed']:
        maxspeed.append(item['max-speed'])

    if item['min-speed']:
        minspeed.append(item['min-speed'])

meandistance = sum(distance)/len(distance)
meanmaxspeed = sum(maxspeed)/len(maxspeed)
meanminspeed = sum(minspeed)/len(minspeed)

tmp = [('distance', meandistance), ('max-speed', meanmaxspeed), ('min-speed', meanminspeed)]

newdataset = dict(tmp)

print(newdataset)
print(type(newdataset))

'''
{'distance': 4343.2, 'max-speed': 597.6, 'min-speed': 227.0}
<class 'dict'>
'''
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `lambda`:

```
mean = lambda elm, key: sum(k.get(key) for k in elm)/len(elm)
final = {'distance': mean(dataset, 'distance'), 'max-speed': mean(dataset, 'max-speed'), 'min-speed': mean(dataset, 'min-speed')}
print(final)
```

Another approach:

```
final = {key: mean(dataset, key) for k in dataset for key, value in k.items() if not isinstance(value, str)}
```

output:

```
{'max-speed': 597.6, 'distance': 4343.2, 'min-speed': 227.0}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use numpy to create various arrays for each key, and then find the mean of those arrays. Then I would add them to a dict. Here is an example:

```
import numpy as np


dataset = [
        {"name": "John",  "distance": 5602,  "max-speed": 504, "min-speed":798},
        {"name": "Mike",  "distance": 5242,  "max-speed": 622, "min-speed":87},
        {"name": "Chad",  "distance": 4825,  "max-speed": 453, "min-speed":34},
        {"name": "Phil",  "distance": 611,   "max-speed": 500, "min-speed":93},
        {"name": "Tyler", "distance": 5436,  "max-speed": 909, "min-speed":123}
        ] 
distances = np.array([value['distance'] for value in dataset])
max_speed = np.array([value['max-speed'] for value in dataset])
min_speed = np.array([value['min-speed'] for value in dataset])

averages = {'distance': float(distances.mean()), 'max-speed': float(max_speed.mean()), 'min-speed': float(min_speed.mean())}
print(averages)
```

Here is your output:

```
{'distance': 4343.2, 'max-speed': 597.6, 'min-speed': 227.0}
```